# How to avoid asking duplicate questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, downvotes, voting, asking-questions

I've had situations in the past when I wanted to ask a certain question and, before doing it, searched Stack Overflow for a similar answered question but didn't find it (probably because I didn't know exactly what my problem was).

Despite my effort, my question was quickly closed and downvoted for being a duplicate from an already-answered question. I understand why it was closed and why it I was referenced to the latter but I don't see why it should get downvotes like that.

Comment: It shouldn't get downvotes *just* for being a duplicate but there's no way to tell why it was downvoted anyway unless the voters commented which is unlikely. If it is a **very** common question then it is likely to be downvoted. All you can do is search the closest terms you can think of and see what comes up. Also, don't just search SO, search The Googler also because you sometimes get better results that way.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I see what you did there :)

Comment: Search, search again, and then search a few more times.

Comment: You have one downvoted question that I can see having less than 10k rep, and it was closed for an entirely different reason.

Answer (score 2):

Reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is the first essential step in avoiding downvotes. Well written, documented and complete questions normally don't get downvotes even if they are common/duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

When you start typing the title for your question a list below the title will be automatically populated:

[image]

Of course there is no guarantee that the list is complete, your question can still be a duplicate of a question that doesn't appear in the list. But the list is a good start - especially when you combine it with the related questions list on the right hand side of the page.